# Chart js label issue in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, charts, chart.js

I used chart js to display data but the labels are not applying properly, it applies to single column

my chart code is :

```
var dates =  ['Lonely','Relationship','Anexity','Hurt','Fear'];
        var ctxallSelect = document.getElementById('Emotional');
        window.allEmotion = new Chart(ctxallSelect, {
            type: 'bar',
            data: {
               labels: dates,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'Lonely',
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(0, 156, 182)'                     
                         ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgb(0, 156, 182)'                                           
                    ],
                    data:[this.state.Lonely],
                    fill: false,
                }, {
                    label: 'Relationship',
                    fill: false,
                    backgroundColor: [
                        'rgb(0, 156, 182)'
                    ],
                    borderColor: [
                        'rgb(0, 156, 182)'
                    ],
                    data:  [this.state.Relationship],
                },
```

But my chart label appear as below:

[image: chart]

[image: expected]

Comment: What is the expected behaviour? Could you explain it with more details?

Comment: Each bar should be in separate column

Comment: can you add your full code at your post?

Comment: Full code is not accepting

Comment: ok, how you define  and how you use your `window.allEmotion`?

Comment: I didn't define window.all emotion how to use it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218919/discussion-between-sabrilogesh-k-and-deivison-sporteman).

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is related to way you are setting your `data` inside `dataset`.

I did a live demo for you solving the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/boring-banach-lvffs?file=/src/App.js

Data is an array, each position of that array means one column, so you should do like:

```
datasets: [
        {
          label: "Lonely",
           .....
          data: [30]
        },
        {
          label: "Relationship",
           .....
          data: [0,45]
        },
```

Comment: Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. this is the error message shown

Comment: if you are not using a functional component, you should remove the `useEffect` and move the code to `componentDidMount`.

Comment: It is in the function which is called in componentDidMount so no isssues